# WebApi Post and Routing in Same Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to learn WebApi and am getting the below error.

Error   CS1929  'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'CreateResponse' and the best extension method overload 'HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage, HttpStatusCode, PilotModel)' requires a receiver of type 'HttpRequestMessage'

I want to return a HTTPResponseMessage from my Post method, and need to inherit from WebApi, but cannot because I'm inheriting from Controller. Do I have my class setup incorrectly? Am I not supposed to mix routing and a WebApi calls? What way should I do this?

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    public RegistrationController()
    {
        this.registrationService = new RegistrationService();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Registration Page";

        return View();
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(PilotModel pilot)
    {
        this.registrationService.RegisterPilot(pilot);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<PilotModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pilot);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a separate controller class for API calls that inherits from `ApiController`.  Mixing controller actions and API controller actions in the same class won't work (yet).

Comment: So, I can have Post(PilotModel pilot) in an API Controller and return a HttpResponseMessage? Is that what I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two different controller classes.

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : Controller
    {
        private RegistrationService registrationService;

        public RegistrationController()
        {
            this.registrationService = new RegistrationService();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Registration Page";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

You may also need to add `[FromBody]` to distinguish that the `pilot` is from the form data and not a URL parameter (assuming you are using a form or otherwise sending the data in the body of the message).

```
namespace MyApp.ApiControllers
{
    public class RegistrationController : ApiController
    {
        private RegistrationService registrationService;

        public RegistrationController()
        {
            this.registrationService = new RegistrationService();
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]PilotModel pilot)
        {
            this.registrationService.RegisterPilot(pilot);

            var response = Request.CreateResponse<PilotModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pilot);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down!